# Autofill logging screen Xcode

Tags: xcode

I need to have an email and password filed auto generated so that in development mode I don't have to fill it out every time,it's very tedious. This is my logging screen:

```
 let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    
    // Signing in the user
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
        
        if error != nil {
            // Couldn't sign in
            self.errorLabel.text = error!.localizedDescription
            self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
        }
        else {
            let salonViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.salonViewController) as? SalonViewController
            
            self.view.window?.rootViewController = salonViewController
            self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }
    }
```

How can I generate that text using XCode 10 via GUI?

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the options under Text this can be set:

[image]

Comment: Why would you do this instead of simply setting the `text` property? `youTextField.text = "test"`

Comment: I tried that one and didn't work. This is temporary for me to not write the login info every time I want to see the changes I made. I will delete it later, but it's mainly what I was asking for.

Comment: I updated my answer based on what you said, there is definitely a better way yes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
let email = emailTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)  
let password = passwordTextField.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

use

```
let email = <your email>
let password <password>
```

and proceed as usual.

alternatively in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let emailTextField.text = <your email>
let passwordTextField.text = <your password>
```

Comment: that doesn't do anything